# Getting the id of a clicked button

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

So , I have been scratching my head since long, to get the ID of the clicked button ,but couldn't get it right. It always returns me `undefined` .

here's the fiddle : http://jsfiddle.net/thinkinbee/mx0rb5cy/

Is there something that i haven't included in my fiddle ? . Is there something wrong in my JS code ?

I took reference of previous questions but nothing seemed to work . I tried to implement both `$(this).attr("id")` and `this.id` but there was no positive result .

Also in the longer go all my buttons would be coming dynamically .any thing extra i will need to handle then ?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If the buttons are dynamic you should use document.on.

I got your fiddle to work like this:  http://jsfiddle.net/1ehy66k9/

```
$(document).on('click', '.ui-btn', function() {
  alert("Clicked with Id "+$(this).attr('id'));
});
```

Comment: works perfectly @Jim thanks, but just a second thought this function would return me all the buttons in the whole document ? Is there any other to get the buttons only from a particular div .(Pardon me for being bad at jquery & JS . I just started to get my hands dirty with them .)

Comment: I'm not great at selectors either.  Something like this?  http://jsfiddle.net/92400whm/

Answer (score 2):

You should pass `this` as a parameter:

```
<a class="ui-btn ui-btn-inline ui-mini" id="check" onclick="chkAlert(this)">click me</a>
```

```
var chkAlert = function(elem){
    alert("Clicked with Id "+$(elem).attr('id'));
    alert("Clicked with Id "+elem.id);
};
```

[JSFiddle Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/mx0rb5cy/5/).

Answer (score 1):

Try this -

HTML -

```
<a class="ui-btn ui-btn-inline ui-mini" id="check" onclick="chkAlert(this)">click me</a>
```

JavaScript -

```
var chkAlert = function(t){
    alert("Clicked with Id "+$(t).attr('id'));

};
```

http://jsfiddle.net/mx0rb5cy/6/

Answer (score 1):

you need to send the button into the function as variable `this`:

```
<a class="ui-btn ui-btn-inline ui-mini" id="check" onclick="chkAlert(this)">click me</a>
```

and then receive it inside the function (you can name it whatever you want inside the function)

```
var chkAlert = function(caller){
    alert("Clicked with Id "+caller.id);
};
```

<kbd>**[Example](http://jsfiddle.net/TheBanana/mx0rb5cy/1/)**</kbd>

Answer (score 1):

you can pass the id to the function like **onclick="chkAlert(this.id)"**, please try as shown

```
<a class="ui-btn ui-btn-inline ui-mini" id="check" onclick="chkAlert(this.id)">click me</a>


var chkAlert = function(id){
    alert("Clicked with Id "+id);
    alert("Clicked with Id "+id);
};
```